# Hausdorff dimension calculation for groups

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I was reading about homogeneous space i.e let $G$ be a Lie group and $\Gamma$ be a discrete subgroup of $G$ with finite covolume. Then Hausdroff dimension of $G / \Gamma$ is the Hausdorff dimension of $G$. I didn't find any proof of the above fact, if someone has any idea about how to prove it or any reference, it would be very helpful. In fact I want to know the proof also for the fact that *Hausdroff dimension of $G$= topological dimension of $G$*.

Any idea or reference where Hausdorff dimension has been calculated for the groups would be very helpful for my understanding purposes.

Comment: Start with the fact that Hausdorff dimension is defined for metric spaces. Thus, presumably, you need an invariant Riemannian metric on $G$. Do you know how to compute Hausdorff dimension of a Riemannian manifold? If not, start with computing Hausdorff dimension of a Euclidean space.

Comment: Yes I know how to calculate it for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and cantor set like sets. Yes for Lie groups we need Riemannian metric to do that. I am saying I know the result that Hausdroff dimension is same as topological dimension for the Lie groups. I am asking how to prove this. I was thinking locally the manifold ( as Lie group is smooth manifold) looks like $\mathbb{R}^d$ so from there something can be said. But how to be precise?

Comment: Cantor set is not a helpful example. Suppose you have two spaces which are bi-Lipschitz homeomorphic to each other. Can you prove that they have the same Hausdorff dimension? Now, think about local geometry of Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: Yes from bi-Lipschitz I can prove that they have same hausdorff dimension just by using definition carefully. Now I am not sure but all we need to show that Riemannian metric structure is bi-Lipschitz with Euclidean ball?Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, plus countable stability of Hausdorff dimension (see Falkoner's book).

Comment: Sorry I was reading that but can you please elaborate where to use countable stability in the comparison of Riemannian metric structure with the Euclidean ball ? Also as I asked the question about $G / \Gamma$, I just want to ask why $dim_{G / \Gamma}=dim_{G}$ where dimension is topological dimension. I know this should be true but can't able to come with idea of the proof.

Comment: @MoisheKohan can you please elaborate the above question I asked? It would be very beneficial for my understanding. Why the topological dimension of both the spaces are same and I am assuming the countable stability may be used in the covering argument but still I want to confirm it with you. It has nothing to do with bi-lIpschitz argument I guess but dimension calculation it's needed, right?

Comment: How much do you know about topological dimension? Can you prove that topological dimension of an n-dimensional manifold equals n?